# How to get a instance of Win32_SecurityDescriptor in WMI?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, wmi, access-violation

i'm writting a C++ WMI utility class which wraps the WMI stuff to help my further WMI query. i encountered a problem when accessing a Win32_SecurityDescriptor instance.

i used the WQL query "Select * from Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting" to get all the Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting instances. then called the GetSecurityDescriptor method of Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting instance to get a Win32_SecurityDescriptor instance. But when i attempted to retrieve some property like "__PATH" from the Win32_SecurityDescriptor instance, i got a 0xC0000005 Access Violation messagebox.

i wrote my code in C++, but i think the problem should be common.
I also used the wbemtest tool by Microsoft for test but didn't find a way to display a Win32_SecurityDescriptor instance. Why is Win32_SecurityDescriptor so special?

here's all my code, you can try it in your VC, mine is 6. Windows SDK maybe needed.
Access Violation found in the caller code:
CString strSDInstancePath = wmiSearcher->getStringFromObject(pSDInstance, "__PATH");

ADWMISearch.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "ADWMISearch.h"

#include <comdef.h>
# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")
# pragma comment(lib, "credui.lib")
# pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")
#include <wincred.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

DWORD ADWMISearch::WIN32_FROM_HRESULT_alternate(HRESULT hr)
{
    DWORD dwResult;
    if (hr < 0)
    {
        dwResult = (DWORD) hr;
        return dwResult;
    }
    else
    {
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("WIN32_FROM_HRESULT_alternate Error."), _T("Error"));
        return -1;
    }
}

IWbemServices* ADWMISearch::connect(CString strServerName, CString strServerIP, CString strDomainName, CString strUsername,
                         CString strPassword)
{
    CString strComputerName = strServerName;
    CString strFullUsername; //_T("adtest\\Administrator")
    if (strDomainName == _T(""))
    {
        strUsername = _T("");
        strFullUsername = _T("");
        strPassword = _T("");
    }
    else
    {
        strFullUsername = strDomainName + _T("\\") + strUsername;
    }


    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        //cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
        //    << hex << hres << endl;
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("connect"));
        return NULL;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY,    // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );

    //char aaa[100];
    //sprintf(aaa, "%x", hres);

    if (FAILED(hres) && hres != RPC_E_TOO_LATE)
        {
            //cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
            //    << hex << hres << endl;
            CoUninitialize();
            MyMessageBox_Error(_T("connect"));
            return NULL;                    // Program has failed.
        }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("connect"));
        return NULL;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    bool useToken = TRUE;
    bool useNTLM = FALSE;
    // Get the user name and password for the remote computer
    /*
    CREDUI_INFO cui;
    bool useToken = TRUE;
    bool useNTLM = FALSE;
    TCHAR pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1] = {0};
    TCHAR pszPwd[CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1] = {0};
    TCHAR pszDomain[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1];
    TCHAR pszUserName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1];
    TCHAR pszAuthority[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1];
    BOOL fSave;
    DWORD dwErr;

    memset(&cui,0,sizeof(CREDUI_INFO));
    cui.cbSize = sizeof(CREDUI_INFO);
    cui.hwndParent = NULL;
    // Ensure that MessageText and CaptionText identify
    // what credentials to use and which application requires them.
    cui.pszMessageText = _T("Press cancel to use process token");
    cui.pszCaptionText = _T("Enter Account Information");
    cui.hbmBanner = NULL;
    fSave = FALSE;

    dwErr = CredUIPromptForCredentials( 
        &cui,                             // CREDUI_INFO structure
        _T(""),                         // Target for credentials
        NULL,                             // Reserved
        0,                                // Reason
        pszName,                          // User name
        CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1,     // Max number for user name
        pszPwd,                           // Password
        CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1,     // Max number for password
        &fSave,                           // State of save check box
        CREDUI_FLAGS_GENERIC_CREDENTIALS |// flags
        CREDUI_FLAGS_ALWAYS_SHOW_UI |
        CREDUI_FLAGS_DO_NOT_PERSIST);  

    if(dwErr == ERROR_CANCELLED)
    {
        useToken = true;
    }
    else if (dwErr)
    {
        cout << "Did not get credentials " << dwErr << endl;
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;      
    }
    */

    // change the computerName strings below to the full computer name
    // of the remote computer
    CString strAuthority;
    if(!useNTLM)
    {
        //StringCchPrintf(pszAuthority, CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1, _T("kERBEROS:%s"), strComputerName);
        strAuthority = _T("kERBEROS:") + strComputerName;

    }

    // Connect to the remote root\cimv2 namespace
    // and obtain pointer pSvc to make IWbemServices calls.
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    CString strNetworkResource = _T("\\\\") + strComputerName + _T("\\root\\cimv2");
    if (strFullUsername == _T(""))
    {
        hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
            _bstr_t(strNetworkResource),
            NULL,                                   // User name
            NULL,                                   // User password
            NULL,                                   // Locale             
            WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT,         // Security flags
            _bstr_t(strAuthority),                  // Authority        
            NULL,                                   // Context object 
            &pSvc                                   // IWbemServices proxy
            );
    }
    else
    {
        hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
            _bstr_t(strNetworkResource),
            _bstr_t(strFullUsername),                   // User name
            _bstr_t(strPassword),                   // User password
            NULL,                                   // Locale             
            WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT,         // Security flags
            _bstr_t(strAuthority),                  // Authority        
            NULL,                                   // Context object 
            &pSvc                                   // IWbemServices proxy
            );
    }

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        DWORD aaa = WIN32_FROM_HRESULT_alternate(hres);
        //cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
        //     << hex << hres << endl;

        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("connect"));
        return NULL;                // Program has failed.
    }

    //cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;


    // step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Create COAUTHIDENTITY that can be used for setting security on proxy

    COAUTHIDENTITY *userAcct = NULL;
    COAUTHIDENTITY authIdent;

    if(!useToken)
    {
        memset(&authIdent, 0, sizeof(COAUTHIDENTITY));
        authIdent.PasswordLength = strPassword.GetLength();
        authIdent.Password = (USHORT*) _bstr_t(strPassword);


        authIdent.Domain = (USHORT*) _bstr_t(strDomainName);
        authIdent.DomainLength = strDomainName.GetLength();
        authIdent.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;

        userAcct = &authIdent;

    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels on a WMI connection ------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
       pSvc,                           // Indicates the proxy to set
       RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
       RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
       COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name 
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
       userAcct,                       // client identity
       EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        //cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
        //    << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("connect"));
        return NULL;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========
    pLoc->Release();

    return pSvc;
}

vector<IWbemClassObject*> ADWMISearch::query(IWbemServices *pSvc, CString strDomainName, CString strPassword, CString strWQL)
{
    vector<IWbemClassObject*> npResultObjects;
    BOOL useToken = TRUE;
    // step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Create COAUTHIDENTITY that can be used for setting security on proxy

    COAUTHIDENTITY *userAcct = NULL;
    COAUTHIDENTITY authIdent;

    if(!useToken)
    {
        memset(&authIdent, 0, sizeof(COAUTHIDENTITY));
        authIdent.PasswordLength = strPassword.GetLength();
        authIdent.Password = (USHORT*) _bstr_t(strPassword);

        /*
        LPTSTR slash = _tcschr(pszName, _T('\\'));
        if( slash == NULL )
        {
            //cout << _T("Could not create Auth identity. No domain specified\n") ;
            pSvc->Release();
            pLoc->Release();     
            CoUninitialize();
            return 1;               // Program has failed.
        }

        StringCchCopy(pszUserName, CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1, slash+1);
        authIdent.User = (USHORT*)pszUserName;
        authIdent.UserLength = _tcslen(pszUserName);
        StringCchCopyN(pszDomain, CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1, pszName, slash - pszName);
        */

        authIdent.Domain = (USHORT*) _bstr_t(strDomainName);
        authIdent.DomainLength = strDomainName.GetLength();
        authIdent.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;

        userAcct = &authIdent;

    }

    // Step 7: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    HRESULT hResult;
    hResult = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        _bstr_t(_T("WQL")), 
        _bstr_t(strWQL), //_T("Select * from Win32_Share")
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        //cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
        //    << " Error code = 0x" 
        //    << hex << hres << endl;
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("query"));
        return npResultObjects;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 8: -------------------------------------------------
    // Secure the enumerator proxy
    hResult = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pEnumerator,                    // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
        COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        userAcct,                       // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities 
        );

    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        //cout << "Could not set proxy blanket on enumerator. Error code = 0x" 
        //     << hex << hres << endl;
        pEnumerator->Release();
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("query"));
        return npResultObjects;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // When you have finished using the credentials,
    // erase them from memory.



    // Step 9: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 7 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        npResultObjects.push_back(pclsObj);
        /*
        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        cout << _T("OS Name: ") << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;

        // Get the value of the FreePhysicalMemory property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"FreePhysicalMemory", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        cout << "Free physical memory(in kilobytes): " << vtProp.uintVal << endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
        pclsObj = NULL;
        */
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pEnumerator->Release();

    return npResultObjects;
}

CString ADWMISearch::getStringFromObject(IWbemClassObject* pObject, CString strPropertyName)
{
    _bstr_t bstrPropertyName = strPropertyName;

    VARIANT vtProperty;
    CString strProperty;
    // Get the value of the property
    VariantInit(&vtProperty);
    HRESULT hResult = pObject->Get(bstrPropertyName, 0, &vtProperty, 0, 0);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && V_VT(&vtProperty) == VT_BSTR)
    {
        strProperty = vtProperty.bstrVal;
        VariantClear(&vtProperty);
        return strProperty;
    }
    else
    {
        VariantClear(&vtProperty);
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getStringsFromObjects"));
        return _T("");
    }
}

vector<CString> ADWMISearch::getStringsFromObjects(vector<IWbemClassObject*> npObjects, CString strPropertyName)
{
    _bstr_t bstrPropertyName = strPropertyName;
    vector<CString> nstrProperties;

    for (int i = 0; i < npObjects.size(); i ++)
    {
        VARIANT vtProperty;
        CString strProperty;
        // Get the value of the property
        VariantInit(&vtProperty);
        HRESULT hResult = npObjects[i]->Get(bstrPropertyName, 0, &vtProperty, 0, 0);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && V_VT(&vtProperty) == VT_BSTR)
        {
            CString strProperty = vtProperty.bstrVal;
            nstrProperties.push_back(strProperty);
            VariantClear(&vtProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            VariantClear(&vtProperty);
            MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getStringsFromObjects"));
            return nstrProperties;
        }
    }
    return nstrProperties;
}

void ADWMISearch::clearObjects(vector<IWbemClassObject*> npObjects)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < npObjects.size(); i ++)
    {
        npObjects[i]->Release();
        npObjects[i] = NULL;
    }
    npObjects.clear();
}

IWbemClassObject* ADWMISearch::getWMIClass(IWbemServices *pSvc, CString strClassName)
{
    HRESULT hResult;
    IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
    hResult = pSvc->GetObject(_bstr_t(strClassName), 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL); //_T("Win32_Share")
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
    {
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getWMIClass"));
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return pClass;
    }
}

IWbemClassObject* ADWMISearch::getObjectFromObject(IWbemClassObject *pObject, CString strArgumentName)
{
    if (!pObject)
    {
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getObjectFromObject"));
        return NULL;
    }

    HRESULT hResult;
    VARIANT varArgument;

    hResult = pObject->Get(_bstr_t(strArgumentName), 0, &varArgument, NULL, 0);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
    {
        VariantClear(&varArgument);
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getObjectFromObject"));
        return NULL;
    }

    //IWbemClassObject **ppResultObject;
    IWbemClassObject *pResultObject2;
    if (V_VT(&varArgument) == VT_UNKNOWN)
    {
        //ppResultObject = (IWbemClassObject **)varArgument.ppunkVal;
        pResultObject2 = (IWbemClassObject *)varArgument.punkVal;
    }
    else if (V_VT(&varArgument) == VT_DISPATCH)
    {
        //ppResultObject = (IWbemClassObject **)varArgument.ppdispVal;
        pResultObject2 = (IWbemClassObject *)varArgument.pdispVal;
    }
    else
    {
        VariantClear(&varArgument);
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getObjectFromObject"));
        return NULL;
    }

    VariantClear(&varArgument);

    //IWbemClassObject *pResultObject = *ppResultObject;
    //return pResultObject;
    return pResultObject2;
}

IWbemClassObject* ADWMISearch::getObjectFromObjectWithCheck(IWbemClassObject *pOutParams, CString strArgumentName)
{
    if (!pOutParams)
    {
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getObjectFromObjectWithCheck"));
        return NULL;
    }

    HRESULT hResult;
    VARIANT varReturnValue;
    VARIANT varArgument;
    hResult = pOutParams->Get(_bstr_t(L"ReturnValue"), 0, &varReturnValue, NULL, 0);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
    {
        VariantClear(&varReturnValue);
        VariantClear(&varArgument);
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getObjectFromObjectWithCheck"));
        return NULL;
    }
    DWORD dwResult = varReturnValue.lVal;

    hResult = pOutParams->Get(_bstr_t(strArgumentName), 0, &varArgument, NULL, 0);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
    {
        VariantClear(&varReturnValue);
        VariantClear(&varArgument);
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getObjectFromObjectWithCheck"));
        return NULL;
    }

    //IWbemClassObject **ppResultObject;
    IWbemClassObject *pResultObject2;
    if (V_VT(&varArgument) == VT_UNKNOWN)
    {
        //ppResultObject = (IWbemClassObject **)varArgument.ppunkVal;
        pResultObject2 = (IWbemClassObject *)varArgument.punkVal;
    }
    else if (V_VT(&varArgument) == VT_DISPATCH)
    {
        //ppResultObject = (IWbemClassObject **)varArgument.ppdispVal;
        pResultObject2 = (IWbemClassObject *)varArgument.pdispVal;
    }
    else
    {
        VariantClear(&varReturnValue);
        VariantClear(&varArgument);
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("getObjectFromObjectWithCheck"));
        return NULL;
    }

    VariantClear(&varReturnValue);
    VariantClear(&varArgument);

    //IWbemClassObject *pResultObject = *ppResultObject;
    //return pResultObject;
    return pResultObject2;
}

vector<ADWMIParam> ADWMISearch::genObjectArguments(CString strArgName, IWbemClassObject *pObject)
{
    vector<ADWMIParam> resultArgs;
    resultArgs.push_back(ADWMIParam(strArgName, pObject));
    return resultArgs;
}

IWbemClassObject* ADWMISearch::callStaticMethod(IWbemServices *pSvc, IWbemClassObject *pClass, CString strClassName,
                                                CString strMethodName)
{
    return callStaticMethod(pSvc, pClass, strClassName, strMethodName, vector<ADWMIParam>());
}

IWbemClassObject* ADWMISearch::callStaticMethod(IWbemServices *pSvc, IWbemClassObject *pClass, CString strClassName,
                                                CString strMethodName, vector<ADWMIParam> &arguments)
{
    _bstr_t bstrClassName = _bstr_t(strClassName);
    _bstr_t bstrMethodName = _bstr_t(strMethodName);
    BOOL bInParams;
    BOOL bOutParams;

    HRESULT hResult;
    IWbemClassObject* pClass2 = getWMIClass(pSvc, strClassName);

    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
    IWbemClassObject* pOutParamsDefinition = NULL;
    hResult = pClass2->GetMethod(bstrMethodName, 0, &pInParamsDefinition, &pOutParamsDefinition);
    if (hResult != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
    {
        //pClass->Release();
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("callStaticMethod"));
        return NULL;
    }
    if (pInParamsDefinition == NULL)
    {
        bInParams = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        bInParams = TRUE;
    }
    if (pOutParamsDefinition == NULL)
    {
        bOutParams = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        bOutParams = TRUE;
    }

    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsInstance = NULL;
    if (bInParams)
    {
        hResult = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pInParamsInstance);

        for (int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); i ++)
        {
            _variant_t varArg;
            VariantCopy(&varArg, &(arguments[i].value));
            hResult = pInParamsInstance->Put(_bstr_t(arguments[i].key), 0, &varArg, 0);
            //hResult = pInParamsInstance->Put(_bstr_t(arguments[i].key), 0, &(arguments[i].value), 0);
        }
    }

    IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
    hResult = pSvc->ExecMethod(bstrClassName, bstrMethodName, 0, NULL, pInParamsInstance, &pOutParams, NULL);
    if (hResult != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
    {
        //pClass->Release();
        if (pInParamsDefinition != NULL)
        {
            pInParamsDefinition->Release();
        }
        if (pOutParamsDefinition != NULL)
        {
            pOutParamsDefinition->Release();
        }
        if (pInParamsInstance != NULL)
        {
            pInParamsInstance->Release();
        }
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("callStaticMethod"));
        return NULL;
    }

    if (pInParamsDefinition != NULL)
    {
        pInParamsDefinition->Release();
    }
    if (pOutParamsDefinition != NULL)
    {
        pOutParamsDefinition->Release();
    }
    if (pInParamsInstance != NULL)
    {
        pInParamsInstance->Release();
    }

    if (bOutParams)
    {
        return pOutParams;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

IWbemClassObject* ADWMISearch::callMethod(IWbemServices *pSvc, IWbemClassObject *pClass, CString strClassName,
                                          CString strInstancePath, CString strMethodName)
{
    return callMethod(pSvc, pClass, strClassName, strInstancePath, strMethodName, vector<ADWMIParam>());
}

IWbemClassObject* ADWMISearch::callMethod(IWbemServices *pSvc, IWbemClassObject *pClass, CString strClassName,
                                          CString strInstancePath, CString strMethodName,  vector<ADWMIParam> &arguments)
{
    _bstr_t bstrClassName = _bstr_t(strClassName);
    _bstr_t bstrMethodName = _bstr_t(strMethodName);
    BOOL bInParams;
    BOOL bOutParams;

    HRESULT hResult;
    //IWbemClassObject* pClass = getWMIClass(pSvc, strClassName);

    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
    IWbemClassObject* pOutParamsDefinition = NULL;
    hResult = pClass->GetMethod(bstrMethodName, 0, &pInParamsDefinition, &pOutParamsDefinition);
    if (hResult != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
    {
        //pClass->Release();
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("callMethod"));
        return NULL;
    }
    if (pInParamsDefinition == NULL)
    {
        bInParams = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        bInParams = TRUE;
    }
    if (pOutParamsDefinition == NULL)
    {
        bOutParams = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        bOutParams = TRUE;
    }

    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsInstance = NULL;
    if (bInParams)
    {
        hResult = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pInParamsInstance);

        for (int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); i ++)
        {
            _variant_t varArg;
            VariantCopy(&varArg, &(arguments[i].value));
            hResult = pInParamsInstance->Put(_bstr_t(arguments[i].key), 0, &varArg, 0);
            //hResult = pInParamsInstance->Put(_bstr_t(arguments[i].key), 0, &(arguments[i].value), 0);
        }
    }

    IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
    hResult = pSvc->ExecMethod(_bstr_t(strInstancePath), bstrMethodName, 0, NULL, pInParamsInstance, &pOutParams, NULL);
    if (hResult != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR)
    {
        //pClass->Release();
        if (pInParamsDefinition != NULL)
        {
            pInParamsDefinition->Release();
        }
        if (pOutParamsDefinition != NULL)
        {
            pOutParamsDefinition->Release();
        }
        if (pInParamsInstance != NULL)
        {
            pInParamsInstance->Release();
        }
        MyMessageBox_Error(_T("callMethod"));
        return NULL;
    }

    if (pInParamsDefinition != NULL)
    {
        pInParamsDefinition->Release();
    }
    if (pOutParamsDefinition != NULL)
    {
        pOutParamsDefinition->Release();
    }
    if (pInParamsInstance != NULL)
    {
        pInParamsInstance->Release();
    }

    if (bOutParams)
    {
        return pOutParams;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

void ADWMISearch::disconnect(IWbemServices *pSvc)
{
    pSvc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

ADWMISearch.h

```
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class ADWMIParam
{
public:
    CString key;
    _variant_t value;
public:
    ADWMIParam(CString strKey, CString strValue)
    {
        key = strKey;
        VariantInit(&value);
        value.vt = VT_BSTR;
        value.bstrVal = _bstr_t(strValue);
    }
    ADWMIParam(CString strKey, IWbemClassObject *pValue)
    {
        key = strKey;
        VariantInit(&value);
        value.vt = VT_UNKNOWN;
        value.punkVal = pValue;
    }
};

class ADWMISearch
{
public:
    DWORD WIN32_FROM_HRESULT_alternate(HRESULT hr);
    IWbemServices* connect(CString strServerName, CString strServerIP, CString strDomainName,
        CString strUsername, CString strPassword);
    vector<IWbemClassObject*> query(IWbemServices *pSvc, CString strDomainName, CString strPassword, CString strWQL);
    CString getStringFromObject(IWbemClassObject* pObject, CString strPropertyName);
    vector<CString> getStringsFromObjects(vector<IWbemClassObject*> npObjects, CString strPropertyName);
    void clearObjects(vector<IWbemClassObject*> npObjects);
    IWbemClassObject* getWMIClass(IWbemServices *pSvc, CString strClassName);
    IWbemClassObject* getObjectFromObject(IWbemClassObject *pObject, CString strArgumentName);
    IWbemClassObject* getObjectFromObjectWithCheck(IWbemClassObject *pOutParams, CString strArgumentName);
    vector<ADWMIParam> genObjectArguments(CString strArgName, IWbemClassObject *pObject);
    IWbemClassObject* callStaticMethod(IWbemServices *pSvc, IWbemClassObject *pClass, CString strClassName,
        CString strMethodName);
    IWbemClassObject* callStaticMethod(IWbemServices *pSvc, IWbemClassObject *pClass, CString strClassName,
        CString strMethodName, vector<ADWMIParam> &arguments);
    IWbemClassObject* callMethod(IWbemServices *pSvc, IWbemClassObject *pClass, CString strClassName,
        CString strInstancePath, CString strMethodName);
    IWbemClassObject* callMethod(IWbemServices *pSvc, IWbemClassObject *pClass, CString strClassName,
        CString strInstancePath, CString strMethodName, vector<ADWMIParam> &arguments);
    void disconnect(IWbemServices *pSvc);
};
```

the call code(a place like main is ok)

```
ADWMISearch *wmiSearcher = new ADWMISearch();
IWbemServices *pSvc = wmiSearcher->connect("luo-pc", "127.0.0.1", "", "", "");
IWbemClassObject *pLSSSClass = wmiSearcher->getWMIClass(pSvc, "Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting");

vector<IWbemClassObject*> npObjects = wmiSearcher->query(pSvc, "", "", "Select * from Win32_Log
```

Comment: I wonder if you run this as admin if it doesn't work.  Sounds like a security issue.  WAG.

Comment: I'm testing it using the administrator account in my Windows 7, which is the most privileged account here, also an Access Denied condition should display an Access Violation error?

Comment: Access Denied in the file system results in a file not found exception.  That's why I said it was a wild ass guess.